# How to route requests to correct consumer in consumer group

Tags: apache-kafka, event-sourcing

From an event sourcing/CQRS perspective: Say I have a consumer group of 2 instances, that's subscribed to a topic. On startup/subscription, each instance processes its share of the event stream, and builds a local view of the data.

When an external request comes in with a command to update the data, how would that request be routed to the correct instance in the group? If the data were partitioned by entity ID so that odd-numbered IDs went to consumer 1 and evens to consumer 2, how would that be communicated to the consumers? Or, for that matter, whatever reverse-proxy or service-mesh is responsible for sending that incoming request to the correct instance?

And what happens when the consumer group is re-balanced due to the addition or subtraction of consumers? Is that somehow automatically communicated the routing mechanism?

Is there a gap in service while the consumers all rebuild their local model from their new set of events from the given topics?

This seems to apply to both the command and query side of things, if they're both divided between multiple instances with partitioned data...

Am I even thinking about this correctly?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Kafka partitioning is great for sharding streams of commands and events by the entity they affect, but not for using this sharding in other means (e.g. for routing requests).

The broad technique for sharding the entity state I'd recommend is to not rely on Kafka partitioning for that (only using the topic partitions to ensure ordering of commands/events for an entity, i.e. by having all commands/events for a given entity be in one partition), but instead using something external to coordinate those shards (candidates would include leases in zookeeper/etcd/consul or cluster sharding from akka (JVM) or akka.net or cloudstate/akka serverless (more polyglot)).  From there, there are two broad approaches you can take:

- (most really applicable if the number of entity shards for state and processing happens to equal the number of Kafka partitions) move part of the consumer group protocol into your application and have the instance which owns a particular shard consume a particular partition
- have the instances ingesting from Kafka resolve the shard for an entity and which instance owns that shard and then route a request to that instance.  The same pattern would also allow things like HTTP requests for an entity to be handled by any instance.  By doing this you're making a service implemented in a stateful manner present to things like a service mesh/container scheduler/load balancer as a more stateless service would present.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is there a mechanism in Kafka for a consumer in a group to determine which ‘shard’ of entity ids it is responsible for? Or is it just based on the hash function used? If it’s the hash function that sounds like Kafka internals, so an instance wouldn’t know, given a particular ID, which other instance might own that data?

Comment: Assuming you're partitioning based on the hash of the entity ID as the key, you can recover the entity ID from the key in the consumer record and then determine the shard that way; alternatively, the consumer record should include the topic partition number, which could by itself be an adequate shard.